# Max Noether's Fundamental Theorem proof in Fulton's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the end of the proof we get that $H=A'F+B'G$ and $A'=\sum A'_i$, $B'=\sum B'_i $ while $A'_i$ and $B'_i$ are forms of degree $i$. I don't understand how then he makes the conclusion that $H=A'_sF+B'_tG$ ? I can't get it... is it because od homogeneity or something? Will be very grateful  if any one could help me! (I am  giving a lecture on this tomorrow noon)

[image]

Comment: The reason is that whenever two polynomials are equal, then each of their homogeneous parts must also be equal. Look hard at the homogeneous parts on each side of the equation, and I bet you will see what you are looking for.